# Falha ao passar menu do html para o CakePHP

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-3

No link abaixo eu tenho um Menu funcionando perfeitamente no Codepen conforme link abaixo:

https://codepen.io/FabricioDev/pen/JOmjEg

Inicio do CSS

```
#DPrincipais
{
  display: block;
}

#TrabalhoRendimento
{
  display: none;
}
#Referencia
{
  display: none;
}
#Comprovante
{
  display: none;
}
.ContForm
{
  border: 1px solid #98adab !important;
  width: 750px !important;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.LabelForms
{
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-top: 0px !important;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #98adab;
}
.InputForms
{
  border: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #98adab !important;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100% !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
```

Fim do Css
Inicio do Menu

```
<nav class="columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <!-- Início Link para Menu DadosPrincipais -->
        <li><?= $this->Html->link('> '.__('Student Data'), '#DPrincipais', ['style' => $dataButton]) ?></li>
    <li><a href="#TrabalhoRendimento">> Trabalho Rendimento</a></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link('> '.'Trabalho','#TrabalhoRendimento', ['style' => $matriculaButton]); ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Fim do Menu
Inicio do Javascript

```
const divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('#DPrincipais,#TrabalhoRendimento,#Referencia,#Comprovante')];
const botoes = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")];

for (let i = 0; i < botoes.length; ++i){ //percorrer todos os botoes
  botoes[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ //definir o click para cada um
    divs.forEach(div => div.style.display = "none"); //esconder todos os divs
    divs[i].style.display = "block"; //mostrar o que foi clicado
  });
}

divs.forEach(div => div.style.display = "none"); //iniciar todos escondidos
divs[0].style.display="block"; //Exibe só a primeira div
```

Fim do Javascript
Inicio do Edite

```
<div id="DPrincipais">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>
         <?php echo __('Dados Básico') ?>
      </legend>
      <div class="ContForm" style="border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px; width: 70% !important; margin-top: -20px;">
         <div class="LabelForms" style="width: 10%;">
            <label for="txtNome">Nome</label>
         </div>
         <div class="InputForms" style="width: 90%; border-right: 0px !important;">
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('nome', ['type' => 'text', 'class' => 'InputLabelUnic', 'name'=>'txtNome',
            'label' => false ]); ?>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ContForm" style="border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px; width: 25% !important; margin-right: 15px; float: right; margin-top: -32px;">
         <div class="LabelForms" style="height: 30px !important; line-height: 30px !important;">
            <label for="txtDataCadastro">Data Cadastro</label>
         </div>
         <div class="InputForms" style="border-right: 0px !important; width: 10% !important; height: 30px !important; line-height: 30px !important;">
            <?= date('d/m/Y'); ?>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="TrabalhoRendimento">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>
         <?php echo 'Trabalho'; ?>
      </legend>
      <!-- Início linha 1 -->
      <div class="ContForm" style="border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px; margin-top: -20px;">
         <div class="LabelForms" style="width: 20% !important;">
            <label for="txtAtivPrinc">Atividade principal</label>
         </div>
         <div class="InputForms" style="width: 30% !important;">
            teste 1
         </div>
         <div class="LabelForms" style="width: 20% !important;">
            <label for="txtSetor">Setor</label>
         </div>
         <div class="InputForms" style="width: 30% !important; border-right: 0px !important;">
            teste 2
         </div>
      </div><!-- Fim linha 1 -->
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

Fim do Edite

Comment: Note que tem um erro no código: `</<fieldset>`

Comment: Cuidado que o `querySelectorAll("li")` apanha todos os `<li>` da página renderizada. Confirme se é isso que pretende, e caso não seja localize mais o seletor adicionando hierarquia

Comment: @ÐvÐ O meu aqui não está com erro.
Não sei o que aconteceu.
Obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade, esse código foi adaptado. 
Não sei se fiz certo mas eu troquei o button por um li que é o que eu estou usando, @Isac.
O que vc me recomenda?

Comment: @Isac
O código original é o seu mesmo. rsrs
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257799/como-manter-uma-div-sempre-ativa/257819#257819
Como vc acha que eu devo fazer?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Xixil
Olha esse erro ao inspecionar o código, @Isac

Comment: @fabricio_wm Pelo erro da imagem parece exatamente o que eu disse. Tem de especificar mais os `<li>` senão acerta em todos. Experimente com algo como `const botoes = [...document.querySelectorAll(".side-nav li")];`, assumindo que os botões que quer dar a funcionalidade de click são os que estão dentro de `<ul class="side-nav">`

Comment: O erro dá na linha 30 desse `script.js`, qual a instrução que está nessa linha ? Clique no inspecionar nessa linha e mostre aqui para se saber exatamente onde tá a dar o erro

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iWHMW
Seria nessa aba, @Isac

Comment: Os quatro primeiros link deveriam apontar para a mesma Div mas estão funcionando como se ele pegasse as divs e distribuísse na sequenciaria para os 4 primeiros menus.

Comment: O código JS tem de ser executado apenas depois de a pagina carregar, caso contrário os botões e/ou `<li>` ainda não existirão. Está a fazer isso ? Executando por exemplo no `onload` do `<body>` ou colocando o código no fim do `<body>`

Comment: @Isac
Fincionou com:
const botoes = [...document.querySelectorAll(".side-nav li")];
Coloca como resposta para finalizar.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seletor que está a utilizar para construir os botões:

```
const botoes = [...document.querySelectorAll("li")];
```

É muito amplo e acaba por acertar em mais elementos que os pretendidos.

Uma forma simples de resolver é acrescentar hierarquia para que acerte apenas nos `<li>` de uma determinada parte do html. Tendo em conta que os `<li>` em causa fazem parte da barra de navegação, a `<ul class="side-nav">`, pode acrescentar esta classe ao seletor para acertar apenas nos `<li>` que estão lá dentro.

Para isso apenas precisa de trocar o obter dos botões para:

```
const botoes = [...document.querySelectorAll(".side-nav li")];
```